# How to go back to the start of a visual selection?

Tags: cursor-motions

I find myself often selecting text and then wanting to go to the start of that selection rather than the end. For example in the following:

[image]

If I press `esc`, it will take me to the end of the selection, but often I find myself wanting to go to the beginning of a visual selection. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Just `o`...and this must be a duplicate.

Comment: @BLayer how would `o` work? Doesn't that create a new line below the current one? Oh -- I mean after the text is un-selected, does the visual mode create a marker or something?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I went to see if I could find an existing answer...otherwise I would add one here. But I got pulled away for a bit. Seems some eager beaver took care of half those steps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the [`o`](https://vimhelp.org/visual.txt.html#v_o) visual-mode command to jump to the "other" end of the visual selection.

Answer (score 1):

For normal mode see: [quasi duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/114019/vim-go-to-beginning-or-end-of-the-visual-area)

You can unify all those mappings. E.g. if `gv` stands for select last visual selection, then append suffix `0` to go to start, or `$` to end:

```
nnoremap gv0 `<
nnoremap gv$ `>
vnoremap gv0 o
vnoremap gv$ o
```

Basic visual block tips: http://vimcasts.org/episodes/selecting-columns-with-visual-block-mode/