# `:g` to move matching lines to the end of the current selection?

Tags: command, movement

I use vim for my todo list:

```
* [ ] A
    * [ ] B
    * [X] C
    * [ ] D
* [ ] E
    * [X] F
    * [X] G
    * [ ] H
```

In order to get the completed tasks out of the way, I can use `:g/\[X\]/m$`, which moves every task with `[X]` to the bottom of the list:

```
* [ ] A
    * [ ] B
    * [ ] D
* [ ] E
    * [ ] H
    * [X] C
    * [X] F
    * [X] G
```

It breaks the tree structure, though (`C` should still be in the `A` branch).

I'd like to move the completed tasks to the bottom of the current selection (e.g. line 1-4, in bold):

```
* [ ] 
    * [ ] 
    * [ ] 
    * [] 
* [ ] E
    * [X] F
    * [X] G
    * [ ] H
```

I [tried](https://superuser.com/a/114087/665295) :

```
:'<,'>g/\[X\]/m\`>
```

[and](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/24864/17615)

```
:'<,'>g/\[X\]/mo
```

but got "Invalid address".

I can specify a line number (`:'<,'>g/\[X\]/m4`), but I would like to find a command without hard-coded line number.

Is there any way to use `:g` to move lines to the end of the current selection?

Alternatively, it would be great to move matching lines to the last line with the same indent, but I have no idea at all how it could be written.

Note: the tree can have more than 2 levels, and once every leaf of a branch is completed, the branch itself is marked as completed (by [vimwiki](https://github.com/vimwiki/vimwiki)):

```
* [ ] A
    * [ ] B
    * [X] C
        * [X] D
        * [X] E
* [X] F
    * [X] G
    * [X] H
* [ ] I
* [X] J
```

Comment: Weird, `:'<,'>g/\[X\]/m\'>` seems to do what I want, even though `\`>` and `'>` appear to be synonym according to `:help \`>`.

Comment: @Quasímodo: The tree can have more than 2 levels, and once every leaf of a branch is completed, the branch itself is marked as completed. I've added a small example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:'<,'>global/\M[X]/move '>` worked for me. There is a difference between the use of backtick and `'` in normal mode and between their use for an `{address}` (see `:help :move`, which links to `:help {address}`, where marks must use `'`).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'm not sure how to use the long command. Using it with the last example in my question, I get `E554: Syntax error in \{...}
E870: (NFA regexp) Error reading repetition limits
E554: Syntax error in \{...}"` I started `/usr/bin/vim -u NONE`, to make sure no plugin is started.

Comment: `:'<,'>global/\M[X]/move '>` works fine, and answers the question in the title.

Comment: Hm, it’s possible the command failed for lines whose indent is 0, which plugs in as -1 repetition. Didnt test that. I may just remove that section @EricDuminil